# What does "system(...)" do in C++?

Tags: c++, python

I am new to python, and I am converting a C++ file into python, but I was not sure how to translate the following lines of C++ code:

```
virtual void show() const override
{ system(("cat " + filename).c_str()); }
```

Comment: I know there is "os" method which can be used but I don't know how?

Comment: Funny, I copy-pasted your title in Google and got a bunch of results that answer your question.

Comment: Poorly written title. You probably meant to ask "What is the Python equivalent of system() in C++?"

Comment: @2rs2ts - "what does `system` do" is a perfectly proper question, and a reasonable one for this problem. Don't get snarky over grammar issues; not everyone speaks and writes English as well as you think you do.

Comment: @PeteBecker I appreciate you defending those whose English is confusing. We have a lot of users for whom English is a second or third language, and it's important to give them the benefit of the doubt. However, I wasn't being picking on someone else's grammar. I was only considering the body of the question. OP wanted to translate some C++ code to Python, and he asked "What does 'system' in c++" which led me to believe he wanted to know what it did so he could translate it to Python; in other words, he wanted to know the equivalent of `system()` is in Python. Or so I assumed; hence "probably."

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/system

Comment: Also note that *translating* code from one language to another is generally a really bad idea - code that is sensible in one language often makes for terrible design in another. C++ and Python are very different languages, *translating* like this will generally result in unpythonic, inefficient, hard to read code. Instead, read the C++ code, figure out what it's intended to do, then implement *that functionality* (not the equivalent to *that code*) in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be sure to `import os` "equivalent" to < cstdlib > < stdlib.h >  where the function system()  is normally implemented.

An exact conversion could looks like:

`os.system(str("cat" + filename))`, however if filename is already a string, then just call as:
os.system("cat" + filename)

Also, I am not so familiar with C++, but knowing ANSI C, it seems like **virtual void show()**
is some method or function therefore you might be looking for:

```
def show(filename):
   os.system("cat" + filename)
#notice that i used the filename as parameter,
#however if its a global variable this is unnecessary.
```

An important advise: it might be implemented inside a class, if the filename variable is "global" or public for methods in this class, then the parameters is not needed.

**Good luck!**

Answer (score 11):

[`system()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) is a function which executes a system command.

Doing this in Python is usually performed with the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python) for more information.

[The docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system) even have a section showing how to replace the `system` call:

```
subprocess.call("cat " + filename, shell=True)
```

---

Python does have a function [`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) that's does *exactly* the same thing as the C function, because it's a thin wrapper around that C function:

> This is implemented by calling the Standard C function system(), and has the same limitations.

And you can easily verify in [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/posixmodule.c#l2788) that this is true.

But as the docs say, "The `subprocess` module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function."

Comment: An edit to my post was suggested, but it was rejected for changing too much. But, it had some good points. As @Kyllopardiun shows, you can use `os.system()` to perform this call too; it seems to be the rough equivalent. I recommend `subprocess` nonetheless, but, references are not bad things.

Comment: It's not just "the rough equivalent"; it's just a thin wrapper around the C function, so it's an _exact_ equivalent.

Comment: Of course, in Python you can call the program directly as well: `subprocess.call(["cat", filename], shell=False)`. This avoids problems with clever users that set `filename` to things like `"/dev/null;rm -rf *"`

Comment: @abarnert Didn't know it was a wrapper. Thanks for the clarification.